# Multi Colored screen with MBA

Tags: macbook-pro

Last morning I turned on my laptop and the screen stuck in this view. 
Does anyone know what kind of problem it might be?

[image][image]

Comment: It's a graphics problem.  Did you try rebooting?

Comment: To follow up on Allan’s answer, try these steps to fix it in this order. Reboot between each step, and if the problem goes away, you can ignore the rest of the steps. 1) reboot, 2) reset nvram, 3) reset pram, 4) run diagnostics. If the first three don’t fix the problem and the diagnostic comes back without errors, edit your question to reflect that and someone will suggest further troubleshooting techniques.

Comment: Hi Noah, thanks for helping. However, problem doesn't get fixed. Any further suggestions?  Cheers